# Returning non-unique values from SOAP response

Tags: html, eclipse, soap, ibm-mobilefirst

So I'm building a mobile application (using IBM Worklight) that consumes a few web services via SOAP calls. I was able to get 3 of the 4 web services working, pulling back values, etc.  The app displays values from the SOAP response in HTML format. This is basically how the values get pulled from the SOAP response and displayed:

```
var submit = result.invocationResult.Envelope.Body.FinSummary.out.SubServices.ServiceName;
```

This has worked fine as long as the values that I want to display are unique.  The final web service's SOAP response is very long and contains repeat values. For example, the SOAP response looks like this:

```
<Envelope>
  <Header/>
    <Body>
      <FinSummary>
        <out>
          <SubServices>
            <....>
            <ServiceName>STRING</ServiceName>
            <....>
          </SubServices>
          <SubServices>
            <....>
            <ServiceName>STRING</ServiceName>
            <....>
          </SubServices>
              <SubServices>
            <....>
            <ServiceName>STRING</ServiceName>
            <....>
          </SubServices>
        </out>
      </FinSummary>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I need to pull out each of those STRING's, but the SubServices/ServiceName nodes are clearly not unique.  Anyone have an idea how to pull these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result.invocationResult.Envelope.Body.FinSummary.out.SubServices is supposed to be parsed as an array, so the following should work:

```
var serviceNames = [];
var subServices = result.invocationResult.Envelope.Body.FinSummary.out.SubServices;
for (var i=0;i<subServices.length; i++){
    serviceNames.push(subServices[i].ServiceName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use HTTP SOAP adapter that will return a JSON to your application?